# How can I transliterate a foreign language into IPA?

Tags: software-recommendation, internationalization, translation

I want to learn an Irish Gaelic song, but the phonology is making my brain hurt. Here's a line:

> ’Sé mo Shaesar, ghille mear

Pronounced like:

```
/ʃe mo hezər ɣɪlə mar/
```

Is there a program that can convert the lyrics to the International Phonetic Alphabet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `espeak -q --ipa` to convert text input to IPA.

Option `-q` means "quiet" -- in this case literally "don't speak".

1. First check that it supports the language:

   ```
   $ espeak --voices
   Pty Language Age/Gender VoiceName          File          Other Languages
   ...
    5  ga             -  irish-gaeilge        europe/ga     
   ...
   ```
2. Then specify the language and feed the line:

   ```
   $ espeak -q -v ga --ipa "’Sé mo Shaesar, ghille mear"
    ʃˈeː mɐ hˈeːʃɐr
    ʁjˈɪlʲlə mˈar
   ```
3. I don't know why the output has leading spaces and a linebreak, but feeding it into `echo` will remove them:

   ```
   $ echo $(espeak -q -v ga --ipa "’Sé mo Shaesar, ghille mear")
   ʃˈeː mɐ hˈeːʃɐr ʁjˈɪlʲlə mˈar
   ```
4. Use `while read` to do the whole lyrics:

   ```
   $ while read line; do
   >     echo $(espeak -q -v ga --ipa "$line")
   > done < "Mo Ghille Mear.txt"
   ʃˈeː mɐ ləˈeːəx mɐ ʁjˈɪlʲlə mˈar
   ʃˈeː mɐ hˈeːʃɐr ʁjˈɪlʲlə mˈar
   nʲˈiː ˈuəɹɐs fˈeːn ˈeːən t̪ˈuən nɑː ʃˈeːn
   ˈoː xˈui̯ɡ ɪ ɡʲˈeːn mɐ ʁjˈɪlʲlə mˈar
   ...
   ```

Comment: On listening again to the song, it seems the machine transcription gets a lot of consonants wrong. Vowels are good for the most part.